# return value from revert using web3

Tags: solidity

Is there anyway to read the return value from revert('Errored out') from Solidity contract via web3.

For example from below code I need to read the value from revert

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
contract sample {
function buy(uint amount) payable {
  if (amount > 12)
     revert('Not enough value');
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. The combination of `if (amount > 12)` and `Not enough value` seems like an oxymoron. You should either change the `>` to `<=`, or the `not enough` to `too much`. 2. The amount is generally passed in `msg.value`, where `msg` is passed to the function (any function) implicitly. So there's no need to pass it as an (explicit) input argument. 3. There is no return-value for `revert`. You can catch this exception when you call the function from the off-chain (web3 client) using standard exception handling, depending on the language that you use (e.g., `try/catch` if you're using Javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of the latest version of Solidity (0.4.24) and the EVM, this is not possible. The transaction is reverted and that's it. It is something which is being worked on and you can track its status on this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/issues/584).